# Hook some regular tasks?

Tags: android, hook

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

I've an app (service) that stays in background, and gets triggered whenever the user

- Adds/deletes/updates a contact
- Installs/uninstalls an app
- Adds/deletes/renames a file on the FS

Do you think this is possible guys? (in a proper way of course, if it's possible to do it by hacking and dirty stuff I'd pass)

I tried to look over the internet a bit but didn't find discussions related to this point.

What's your guess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried any of this myself, but:

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/observing-content.html seems to deal with detecting contact data changes. Basically you need to register a `ContentObserver` and handle the changes you are notified of.

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html - from that you can register a BroadcastReceiver to be notified of applications being installed or uninstalled. Look for `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`

Please refer to [How to detect file or folder changes in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604223/how-to-detect-file-or-folder-changes-in-android) for how to detect when files are changed in the filesystem. You may be limited to your sandbox with a FileObserver, I'm not sure. Also - a rename doesn't seem to be explicitly notified, but you will probably detect it from a `MOVED_FROM` followed by `MOVED_TO`, or possibly a `DELETE` followed by `CREATE`

Comment: Wow: Straight to the hole ! Thank you very much. No comment :)

Comment: No probs. It's worth pointing out that you can't actually prevent or affect these operations in any way, so it's not really a hook in the traditional sense - it's just a notification.

Comment: Fair enough, and I don't require more than that, a simple notification is just perfect :). Thank you again ;)

Comment: do you know if anyway that allows getting the identifier of the contact being affected in the case of contacts watching ?

Answer (score 1):

Found in the SDK sample for SDK version 5+:

```
     /**
     * Retrieves the contact information.
     */
    @Override
    public ContactInfo loadContact(ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri contactUri) {
        ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
        long contactId = -1;

        // Load the display name for the specified person
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contactUri,
                new String[]{Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactId = cursor.getLong(0);
                contactInfo.setDisplayName(cursor.getString(1));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        // Load the phone number (if any).
        cursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{Phone.NUMBER},
                Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " DESC");
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactInfo.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(0));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contactInfo;
    }
```

You can specify the contact columns you want to retreive with `Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contactUri, new String[]{Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);` The column names are described at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html and looking at the sample, it seems `cursor.getLong(0)` here is the contact ID you're looking for. It also seems that it is volatile depending on how the contact is edited and how others are added, but you're catching those too so you should be able to handle those cases.

Comment: Thank you man ! I think I've all I need now thanks to you. Kind regards