# Requesting feedback on unistall

Tags: android

Is there a way to request feedback from user on app when user is uninstalling the app on his device?

Answer (score -1):

yes

You can use "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" to broadcast the application package that has been removed.

[how implement broadcastrecevier for uninstall particular application in device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815028/how-implement-broadcastrecevier-for-uninstall-particular-application-in-device)

Comment: I think that this broadcast isn't sent to the package being uninstalled (only to all other apps).