# i want to create a notification in my android application

Tags: android, android-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to Detect file or folder changes In Android?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604223/how-to-detect-file-or-folder-changes-in-android)

hi,
i have a text file on my server contenting messages with message id .now i want to create a Notification in my android application when a message is added in the text file to display the message.can anyone share me some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

To show a notification isn't the problem, you could simply use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) or a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

The tricky part is to check the File for updates. Do you already have something on this?

Comment: no i have not done it yet.i am also stuck in this part.can you please suggest me some way out or it will be very helpful for me if you can share some demo code.