# How to detect that something is going to be deleted

Tags: java, android

Can anybody tell me if is it possible to detect that something is going to be deleted from device like picture, sms, mms, audio video etc. Like in Windows, when something is deleted it appears in recycle bin. I want to save the deleted item as it is a project requirement(If Possible)

Comment: Did you tried to search this first? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Study about fileobserver

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I said I have no idea

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: @AmitKumar your logic perfect

Comment: @FarhanAli Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604223/how-to-detect-file-or-folder-changes-in-android .Just check the logic

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks

Comment: 'if is it possible to detect that something is going to be deleted'. No that is not possible. As nothing/nobody will tell at forehand that it will be done. 'Like in Windows, when something is deleted'. That is AFTER. Not BEFORE.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to be notified when a file is deleted with a FileObserver as has been noted in the comments. To catch a delete event, you can use this:

```
String path = "/home/tim/files/test.txt";
FileObserver obs = new FileObserver(path) {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
    if (event == FileObserver.DELETE) {
      // do your thing.
    }
  }
};
obs.startWatching();
```

Note that this is to watch a specific file. You can also watch an entire directory, by adjusting the path to point to a directory, e.g.: `String path = "/home/tim/files";`

Also note that this means the file is already deleted and you're too late to intervene and prevent the deletion. To my knowledge, that is not even possible. Undeleting a file sounds like an option, but is nothing straightforward either.

What you could do however, is to recreate the file upon deletion. Maybe pull it from a server if you have one. Depends on the contents of the file.

Comment: what type of path is this ?
String path = "/home/tim/test.txt";

Comment: @FarhanAli that is a path on my linux pc that i used as example. You have to put the path on the android device there instead.

Comment: Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html#DELETE), the `DELETE` event type indicates that "A file was deleted from the monitored directory". The past tense would indicate that `FileObserver` finds out *after* the file was deleted, which would not help the OP. If you have evidence that the docs are wrong, let us know!

Comment: @CommonsWare actually I want to catch up the item which is going to delete.